# GRASS - r.mask analogous for vectos

Tags: grass-gis, vector, masking, regionalization

I am working with `r.stats`. My analysis is about overlap Extreme Climatic Events (ECE) raster map with mammals range maps. I used to do my analysis first creating `r.mask` on ECE map and then applying `r.stats` to raster range map for single animal. I discovered I cannot use raster maps for resolution matters, so I have available only vector range maps. It means I have to invert the process and do my statistics on ECE map: so first selecting the region/mask to work on, e.g. the vector range map, and the apply `r.stats` on ECE raster map.

As `r.mask` is only usable for rasters, should I then use `g.region` for vector range maps? Would it work the same?

Comment: I cannot understand the part "I discovered I cannot use raster maps for resolution matters, so I have available only vector range maps". Do you mean you cannot use the raster data because of the resolution? If Micha on his answer got your problem right, then please indicate if it is solved. If you are asking about the r.mask functionality with vectors, actually you can use a vector layer as a mask from the r.mask tool.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need an analogous of `r.mask` for vectors for your task. `r.stats` is a command for rasters (that's what the "r." means), so it will only work within the mask, if you created one. If you want to clip the vector then you could use `g.region` -> `v.in.region` and then use the created vector to clip the one of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking. If I understand correctly, you have a raster of Extreme Climate Events, and a vector polygon map of animal habitat ranges. And your goal is to extract statistics from the ECE raster for each polygon in the ranges vector. If this is correct, then you probably want to look at the `v.rast.stats` module. The manual page is [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.rast.stats.html). Yu can get maximum, minimum, mean, std. dev. and other statistics from the raster map, for each polygon separately.

You **will** need to set the region, using `g.region`. You can use the polygon vector map to set the region. i.e.

```
g.region -p vect=<your ranges polygon vector map>
```